# Appending average to a list with a string and integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have the following file in a .csv format:

```
Lee,6,3,4
John,5,6,8
Luke,2,3,8
Terry,4,7,6
```

and the following code for reading the file and storing it in a list so I can sort by any column.

```
import sys, csv, operator
from statistics import mean

reader = csv.reader(open("O:\\Class 1.csv"), delimiter=",")
sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print(sortedlist)
```

What I am attempting to do is to add an average for each of the pupils and append this to the list. It should look like this:

```
Lee,6,3,4,4.3
John,5,6,8,6.3
Luke,2,3,8,4.3
Terry,4,7,6,5.6
```

What is the easiest way of doing this? Many thanks for any help in advanced.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? You just have to take the `mean` of all but the first column. Slicing is the way to do this: `row = ['Lee', '6', '3', '4']; print(row[1:])` gives you `['6', '3', '4']`. To apply the `mean` function to that, you'd have to convert the strings to `int` first.

Comment: for sublist in sortedlist:
        x = list(map(int, sortedlist[1:][1][1:]))
        x = mean(x)
        sublist.append(x)

So the code above will append the average to the end of the list. However, it is stuck on [1:][1][1:] is there anyway I can add a simple counter to the for loop to make it work? 

Replacing the 1's with an int variable x which was a counter didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas.DataFrame` to do this is quit easy. All the reading, sorting and appending averages can be done with 3 lines of code.

```
df = pandas.read_csv('./xx.csv', header=None)
df.sort(1, ascending=False, inplace=True) # sort by column 1
df['avg'] = df.mean(axis=1)
```

After that, you can print `df`, which should look like

```
       0  1  2  3       avg
0    Lee  6  3  4  4.333333
1   John  5  6  8  6.333333
3  Terry  4  7  6  5.666667
2   Luke  2  3  8  4.333333
```

You can write this to a new csv file.

```
df.to_csv('./yy.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

see http://pandas.pydata.org/